# C array corrupted after calling a function

Tags: c, arrays, random

I have a simple C program which is supposed to fill an array with random values (this is the beginning of a school assignment). I'm using rand(), seeding it with srand(time()). Because this tended to generate somewhat predictable results when run repeatedly in a certain time period, I made another very simple function to give me a somewhat more random seed value:

```
time_t getRandomSeed(int numberOfIterations)
{
    int i;
    time_t result=time();

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++)
    {
        result = randomizeSeed(result);
    }

    return result;
}

time_t randomizeSeed(time_t seed)
{
    time_t result, fullTime, Modifier1, Modifier2;

    srand((unsigned int)seed);
    fullTime = time();
    Modifier1 = time() >> (rand() % 10);
    Modifier2 = (unsigned short)time();
    Modifier2 <<= (rand() % 9 + 9);

    result = fullTime ^ Modifier1 ^ Modifier2;

    return result;
}
```

In main, I'm calling this inside srand() after declaring 2 int arrays. When I return to main, these arrays are garbage, and I can't figure out why.

```
int main(void)
{   
    int randomNumbers[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    int sortedNumbers[ARRAY_LENGTH];

    srand((unsigned int)getRandomSeed(2));

    fillArray(randomNumbers, sizeof(randomNumbers) / sizeof(randomNumbers[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

I set a breakpoint at line 4, and I have a perfectly normal unititialized array (at 0x00e1ea70 in the most recent run). Then I set another breakpoint at line 8, so I could see the array just before it was passed into fillArray. At this point, the address of the array is somehow 0xfffff04c, and all the elements show "unable to read memory", which I guess makes sense given the address is garbage.

Can anybody give me a clue what's happening to my array?

*Note, this is for a school assignment, so I don't really care if the RNG is secure, nor can I use any 3rd party libraries.

Update:
Per request, this is the body of fillArray(). However, from my question, the problem happens before we ever get to fillArray(), as I'm setting the breakpoint before it get's called.

```
void fillArray(int array[], size_t length)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand()%1000 + 1;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what function `fillArray` looks like???

Comment: The address of local variables (including arrays) doesn't change throughout their lifetime.

Comment: And the most important thing is missing of course (`fillArray` definition??)

Comment: Is this question about filling arrays or about random numbers? Get the array stuff right first, and then if you aren't happy with `rand()` or `srand()` put in a replacement function that will leave everything else intact.

Comment: this statement:  'srand(time())' should be: 'srand(time(NULL))'  you need to pay attention to the man page info as details count

Comment: pretty sure @user3629249 has it. `time(time_t *ptr)` writes to `*ptr`. Leaving it uninitialized means it writes to a garbage location.

Comment: @EOF That would be my expectation. However, in the debugger it showed a different address after calling srand() on line 6 of main.

Comment: time increments at the rate of once per second.  so the seed will be different once each second.   This is plenty fast enough.  Just wait more than one second before running the program again.

Comment: @Bryan: undefined behaviour is not required to cause damage *every* time. You're also calling `time()` in `getRandomSeed()` incorrectly.

Comment: @user3629249 That does indeed seem to be the issue. I just looked for a parameter list in VS and didn't see one. I don't quite understand what is happening still though. Would you mind making that first comment into an answer?

Comment: @user3629249 I am aware that it changes, but for some reason the output was very similar each run. I would have thought that, like a hash function, changing a single digit would alter the output significantly. That doesn't seem to be the case with rand() and srand(), at least in my limited experimentation.

Comment: ...and of course, the weekly notice: take srand() outside the function/loop.

Comment: of course the array has garbage BEFORE calling fillArray,.  It will contain what ever is in the stack memory

Comment: @EOF Good point. I actually didn't realize that I was invoking undefined behavior, which was my problem.

Comment: So I just saw that this question was downvoted... Could anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `randomizeSeed()` you are calling `time()` three times in succession without an argument.

```
fullTime = time();
Modifier1 = time() >> (rand() % 10);
Modifier2 = (unsigned short)time();
```

The function prototype is

```
time_t time(time_t *timer);
```

So you should pay attention to your compiler warnings. From this point on, you have Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only warning I got from the compiler was:  
'time' undefined; assuming extern returning int

Comment: So you should have put `#include <time.h>` - I repeat: *pay attention to the compiler warnings* even if "there was only one".

Comment: Edit:
^^Beat me to the punch.

Oh, and now I know why. I didn't include time.h, so I have no idea what time function VS was using.

Comment: The linker found it, but the compiler did not know the function prototype and so its required arguments. In such a case it assumes the return value is `int`. What lesson have you learnt today? As commented above re the call to `srand()`, if the argument for `time()` is not `NULL`, in this case undefined, the function still writes the time somewhere, but who knows where?

Comment: @Bryan also, since you are learning, you should have `-Wall`,  `-std=c99` (or `-std=c11`) , `-pedantic` and optionally `-Werror` flags for gcc or equivalent flags for your compilers enabled

Comment: WeatherVane - Thanks for all the insight. @MAKZ I will look into those flags, thank you. I am currently using VS as required for this course, FYI, the I used netBeans with gcc in the past.